# Issue with Sub queries / Joins in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can I join the below two queries to one query using sub queries or joins from same table.

```
select case#
from _CB_Orders
GROUP BY case#
HAVING COUNT (case#) >1;

select Distinct RFMS_Inv_Num, case#
from _CB_Orders
```

Any help..

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select RFMS_Inv_Num, case#
from _CB_Orders
where RFMS_Inv_Num <> 'AETEST' and
      case# in (select case#
                from _CB_Orders
                GROUP BY case#
                HAVING COUNT(case#) > 1
               );
```

Details on cases that appear more than once?

Comment: Yes, I need the same. But my fault RFMS_Inv_Num should be distinct.

Comment: Then try `select distinct RFMS_Inv_Num, case#` in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Upto my understanding you are trying to group by `RFMS_Inv_Num` and `case#`

```
 select RFMS_Inv_Num,case#
 from _CB_Orders
 GROUP BY RFMS_Inv_Num, case#
 HAVING COUNT (*) >1;
```

If this is not, then please edit you question or comment